# UIBarButtonItem Exceeds Below UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

`UIBarButtonItem` exceeds its boundary below the `UINavigationBar`. That is, when I click just below the `UIBarButtonItem` the action occurs. Here is my sample code,

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(call:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=rightButton;
```

And action,

```
-(IBAction)call:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"clicked");
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I executed your code.Its working fine..Please check your navigation bar height and also check your navigation bar image size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal and expected behavior.

`UIBarButtonItem` extends 5 pixels below the navigation bar.

This is iOS approach for reducing user's frustration on tap misfire.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But I have a `UIButton` just below The `UIBarButtonItem`, So when I click the `UIButton` it happens to occur the `UIBarButtonItem` event.

Comment: I know and I understand. It is very frustrating. Apple is breaking their own rules ; I think it has to do with the 44x44 points minimum recommended size for UI widgets. If you absolutely positively cannot work around this limitation, and get can do away without the Navigation bar, then do this: *create a 44 pix tall navigation-looking bar in your own view*. It's a kludge I am guilty of having used in places where I needed a very custom-looking NavigationBar that was just too difficult to implement...